# SQL OLE Automation Granting Access To A Linux Share

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, automation, ole

I'm pretty desperate for some guidance on this.

I've been running for years a [SQL function](https://www.sqlindia.com/file-system-operations-in-sql-server-using-ole-automation/) that uses OLE Automation to retrieve file statistics in an important workflow.

Recently a NAS vendor i have changed their firmware breaking "Guest Access".  The NAS throws "access denied" errors now.  After troubleshooting, the vendor is resisting fixing this, instructing me to "get my program to pass credentials."

I have a windows credential setup but apparently that is now what's being used under the hood here.

**How can i pass credentials from my linux based nas when using OLE Automation?**

The code is below for reference.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_fileOperation]
(
@filPath VARCHAR (500),
@flg TINYINT = 1 -- 1 Select, 2 Stream, 3 Delete
)
RETURNS
@var TABLE
(
[FileName] varchar (500)
, [Type] varchar (200)
, [CreatedDate] datetime
, [LastAsscessedDate] datetime
, [LastModifiedDate] datetime
, [FullPath] varchar (500)
, [ShortPath] varchar (500)
, [Attribute] int
, [Operation] varchar(10)
, [FileText] varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @init INT,
@fso INT,
@objFile INT,
@errObj INT,
@errMsg VARCHAR (500),
@fullPath VARCHAR (500),
@shortPath VARCHAR (500),
@objType VARCHAR (500),
@dateCreated datetime,
@dateLastAccessed datetime,
@dateLastModified datetime,
@attribute INT,
@objSize INT,
@fileName varchar (500),
@operation varchar(10),
@objStream INT,
@string varchar(max) = '',
@stringChunk varchar(8000),
@qBreak INT

SELECT
    @init = 0,
    @errMsg = 'Step01: File Open'
EXEC @init = sp_OACreate    'Scripting.FileSystemObject',
                    @fso OUT
IF @init = 0 SELECT
    @errMsg = 'Step02: File Access '''
    + @filPath + '''',
    @errObj = @fso
IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAMethod   @fso,
                                'GetFile',
                                @objFile OUT,
                                @filPath
IF @init = 0
SELECT
    @errMsg = 'Step03: Access Attributes'''
    + @filPath + '''',
    @errObj = @objFile

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'Name',
                                    @fileName OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'Type',
                                    @objType OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'DateCreated',
                                    @dateCreated OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'DateLastAccessed',
                                    @dateLastAccessed OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'DateLastModified',
                                    @dateLastModified OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'Attributes',
                                    @attribute OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'size',
                                    @objSize OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'Path',
                                    @fullPath OUT

IF @init = 0 EXEC @init = sp_OAGetProperty  @objFile,
                                    'ShortPath',
                                    @shortPath OUT

EXEC sp_OADestroy @fso
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objFile 

SELECT @fso = NULL, @objFile = NULL, @operation = 'Selected'

IF @flg = 2
BEGIN
    EXECUTE @init = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @fso OUT

    IF @init=0 EXECUTE @init = sp_OAMethod  @fso,
                                    'OpenTextFile',
                                    @objStream OUT,
                                    @fullPath,
                                    1,
                                    false,
                                    0
    WHILE @init = 0
    BEGIN
       IF @init = 0 EXECUTE @init = sp_OAGetProperty @objStream, 'AtEndOfStream', @qBreak OUTPUT

       IF @qBreak <> 0  BREAK

       IF @init = 0 EXECUTE @init = sp_OAMethod  @objStream, 'Read', @stringChunk OUTPUT,4000
       SELECT @String=@string+@stringChunk
    END

    IF @init=0 EXECUTE @init = sp_OAMethod  @objStream, 'Close'

    EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objStream
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @fso
    SET @operation = 'Stream'
END

SELECT @fso = NULL, @objFile = NULL

IF @flg = 3
BEGIN
EXEC @init = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @fso OUTPUT
EXEC @init = sp_OAMethod @fso, 'DeleteFile', NULL, @fullPath
EXEC @init = sp_OADestroy @fso
SELECT @operation = 'Deleted'
END

INSERT INTO @var
    VALUES (@fileName, @objType, @dateCreated, @dateLastAccessed, @dateLastModified, @fullPath, @shortPath, @attribute, @operation, @string)

RETURN
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: MS sql server 2019.  OLE automation is properly enabled. It works on all shares except the linux based share.  it used to work on the share but now the nas manufacturer is requiring that i pass credentials.